# with index, returns different result

Tags: mysql, optimization

Never seen this before. Running the same query, 1 forces an index. Without the index, the results are incorrect (in wrong order), with the index the results are in the correct order. Only problem with using the index is that its slower for some reason. Index is on comment_id and user_id

without index:

```
SELECT DISTINCT topic_id FROM comments
WHERE user_id=9384
AND (status = 1 or status = 0)
ORDER BY comment_id DESC LIMIT 15
```

with index:

```
SELECT DISTINCT topic_id FROM comments force index(index_comment_user)
WHERE user_id=9384
AND (status = 1 or status = 0)
ORDER BY comment_id DESC LIMIT 15
```

Any ideas? I really want to get the correct order without slowing the query down. I would have throught an index would have done that.

Here is the SQL structure.

```
CREATE TABLE  `db`.`comments` (
  `comment_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `old_comments_id` mediumint(8) unsigned default NULL,
  `user_id` mediumint(8) unsigned default NULL,
  `content` text character set latin1,
  `status` tinyint(3) unsigned default NULL,
  `added_date` datetime default NULL,
  `category_id` tinyint(3) unsigned default NULL,
  `helpful` tinyint(3) unsigned default NULL,
  `modified_date` datetime default NULL,
  `topic_id` mediumint(8) unsigned default NULL,
  `last_mod_user_id` mediumint(8) unsigned default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  USING BTREE (`comment_id`),
  KEY `Index_user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `Index_added_date` (`added_date`),
  KEY `Index_comments_status` USING BTREE (`status`),
  KEY `Index_user_activity` USING BTREE (`comment_id`,`user_id`),
  KEY `Index_user_activity2` USING BTREE (`user_id`,`topic_id`),
  KEY `Index_question_id` USING BTREE (`topic_id`,`status`),
  KEY `Index_user_activity3` (`user_id`,`status`,`topic_id`,`comment_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2040237 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Is mysql picky about the order of the columns in an index - i.e. if you create an index on user_id, column_id instead would that help?

Comment: Please also show the exact table definition.

Comment: Can you define in plain English what result you want, exactly?

Comment: I purpose of this query is to retrieve a list of unique forum topics that a defined user has commented on lately (ordered by most recently commented).

Comment: I don't see an index for "index_comment_user" in the table schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use of DISTINCT together with an ORDER BY on a column you are not selecting will give you problems. Try using a GROUP BY instead:

```
SELECT topic_id, MAX(comment_id) AS comment_id
FROM comments
WHERE user_id=9384 AND status IN (0, 1)
GROUP BY topic_id
ORDER BY comment_id DESC
LIMIT 15
```

You shouldn't need to force the index. Just add the correct index and it should be used automatically. You might want to try different combinations and ordering of the columns in the index to see which works best.

Comment: that query is fine, however. It doesn't consider that I want to get the most recently commented topics. Thus I need an order by comment_id on it which than throws a filesort which isn't nice.

Comment: "It doesn't consider that I want to get the most recently commented topics.": I had min instead of max (I didn't notice the DESC). This is fixed now.

Comment: That doesn't exaclty fix the problem. I still need th order. As you need to select the topics with the MAX comment id, not just the first 15. So ORDER BY comment_id doesnt that, but filesort occurs.

Answer (score 0):

The [manual says](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html)

> If the table has a multiple-column index, any leftmost prefix of the index can be used by the optimizer to find rows. For example, if you have a three-column index on (col1, col2, col3), you have indexed search capabilities on (col1), (col1, col2), and (col1, col2, col3).

i.e. I think you need an index on `user_id, column_id` for your query - it doesn't sound like mysql can use `column_id, user_id`. You should run `EXPLAIN SELECT` on both of the queries to verify this.

Why it goes wrong with the other index I don't know sorry.

Answer (score 0):

This is the common "max per group" problem, and usually it is solved like this:

```
SELECT
  comment.user_id, 
  comment.topic_id,
  comment.comment_id
FROM
  comment
  INNER JOIN (
      SELECT user_id, topic_id, MAX(comment_id) AS comment_id
        FROM comments 
    GROUP BY user_id, topic_id
  ) AS max ON max.comment_id = comment.comment_id
WHERE
  comment.user_id = 9384
  AND comment.status IN (1, 0)
ORDER BY
  comment.comment_id DESC
```